# Google Forms Apps Script to create Subfolders for media

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Multi-Step Google Form with file uploads, I need to save the File uploads into Sub Folders for every entry made to the form.

**My script**

```
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = "FolderIDHere";

const initialize = () => {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
};

const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
  try {
    // Get some useful data to create the subfolder name
    const firstItemAnswer = response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse() // text in first answer
    const user = response.getRespondentEmail()  // email (Collect email addresses must be enabled)
    const time = response.getTimestamp()  // when the response was submited
    const subfolderName = firstItemAnswer + ' ' + user + ' ' + time 
  
    // Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
    const files = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter(
        (itemResponse) =>
          itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD"
      )
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    if (files.length > 0) {
      // Each form response has a unique Id
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
      const subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        // Move each file into the custom folder
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

The script works fine, but for some reason creates 4-5 subfolders (1 for each step, I'm not sure?)

**What I need:**
If the script could simply place all uploads into 1 subfolder instead that would be great.

Anyone with a possible solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This code works 100%

Turns out I had some old triggers creating the problems.